# Is there any way to access Hive (Dataproc) through Nodejs or Python flask?

Tags: python, node.js, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to build a server which can access the data from the hive(Dataproc)/Bigquery/Bigtable like GCP services what is the procedure to connect and access the data from these DBS through NodeJS or Python?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'll need to:

1. Select / create a google cloud project
2. Enable billing for your project
3. Set up authentication
4. Enable APIs
5. Download the client libraries

Here are the instructions for cloud bigtable:

- python set up instructions: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigtable/latest
- nodejs set up instructions: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigtable/latest

There are also some samples you can look at:

- python: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigtable/tree/main/samples
- nodejs: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigtable/latest#samples